# Decoding string in base 64

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, base64

I need to decode a base 64 string. To do so I use the folowing code :

```
// Get the base 64 string vector.
NSString *vector64String = insertRequestDictionnary[@"check"];
// Decode the base 64 string into data.
NSData *vector64Data = [NSData dataFromBase64String: vector64String];
// Get the string from decoded data.
NSString *decodeVector = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: vector64Data
                                               encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

..But every time i get a nil string (decodeVector).
I check with this website (http://www.base64decode.org/), my first string (vector64string) is base 64. For example : "h508ILubppN1xLpmXWLfnw==" gives "< uĺf]bߟ"

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information about this "vector", what generated it and what its used for? This `NSData` extracted from this base 64 string is not a UTF8 string (and if it were, it probably wouldn't have base 64 encoded in the first place). It's hard to provide counsel on how to interpret the resulting binary data, though, without a little context on what the original vector was.

Comment: the vector is a key.
 Im trying to do an AESCrypt decryption between iOS and PHP : A server send me a crypted message and a key (vector64String). To decrypt the message, i use a method and put this key as a parameter. But i first need to decode this key which is in base 64.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using on the iOS side, but AES crypto doesn't generally require the key to be a string. Looks like this is a 16 byte binary key.

Answer (score 0):

Not all data is an NSUTF8String. The point of Base64 to to create a string representation of data that is not naturally a string.

```
NSString *vector64String = @"h508ILubppN1xLpmXWLfnw==";
NSData *vector64Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:vector64String options:0];
NSLog(@"vector64Data: %@", vector64Data);
```

NSLog output:

> vector64Data: <879d3c20 bb9ba693 75c4ba66 5d62df9f>

`vector64Data` **is** the decoded base64 string.

The vector64Data is not a UTF8 string, it is just data.

Comment: so you mean i will always have a nil string (decodeVector) at the end ?

Comment: With this data yes. But what you are trying to do is not correct. What are you trying to accomplish? Do some research on Base64, why it is used, what data is.

Comment: vector64String is a key, written in base 64. I just need to decode vector64String and get the nsutf8 string. 
Okay I will.

Comment: There isn't an NSUTF8 string for the data. What are you using the key for? In many cases such as encryption keys are 8-bit data, not usually strings. What are you using the key for?

Comment: Im trying to do an AESCrypt decryption between iOS and PHP : A server send me a crypted message and a key (vector64String). To decrypt the message, i use this key.
But i first need to decode this key which is in base 64.

Comment: On iOS encryption is done with CommonCrypto, AES128 requires a 128-bit (16-byte) key, that is what `vector64Data` is. If you are having trouble with encryption ask a question about that and supply the code you are trying to get working. Provide a link here to the new question and I will try and help you with it.